# What Spring class is responsible for executing schema.sql?

Tags: java, spring, schema

I am making my own ORM and I'm at the point where I need to push the SQL code I've generated from my entity classes to the database.  I do not aim to copy how Spring does it but rather see what phase of the lifecycle it runs in and how exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual class that read `schema.sql` and execute it is [`DataSourceInitializer#createSchema()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d5b944140aab0d08d70a23188885f6c7eb3fd40e/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializer.java#L93).

Here are the high level flow which somehow triggers it :

1. If `DataSource` class is found from the class-path , spring-boot auto-configuration will enable `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`
2. `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` imports `DataSourceInitializationConfiguration`
3. `DataSourceInitializationConfiguration` registers `DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor` which will be executed and force initialising `DataSourceInitializerInvoker`.
4. `DataSourceInitializerInvoker` 's `afterPropertiesSet` will then execute `DataSourceInitializer#createSchema()` to read and execute `schema.sql`